# What are the differences between Azure SignalR and Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-queues

Microsoft Azure offers both Azure SignalR services and Azure Queue services.  What I can't find is what are the pros/cons of using one versus the other.

Could you either provide those differences here or provide a link to a document or web page that compares them, I've not been able to find anything here or by using Google.

We have a web app and a mobile app these are connecting to Azure Functions.

We need to add the ability to send messages to a Windows Service at a remote location that connects to printers.

Originally I was thinking Azure Service Bus with Subscribe Queues so these remote systems would subscribe to a queue looking for messages for them to process with filters.

Now someone brought up using Azure SignalR instead so I'm trying to understand the differences between the two offerings from Microsoft so I know which one will be more scalable.

Web says print this item calls REST Azure Functions to generate what is to be printed and then that information needs to get to the remote location to be printed.   These networks are not connected so there is no way to directly communicate to the printers which is why the thought of using Azure Service Bus messages or Azure SignalR messaging.

Answer (score 4):

you won't find because they solve different problems. Azure SignalR is a fully managed websocket service, while Azure Queue is a messaging service which is part of Azure Storage.

To compare you need to select services that solve the same problem.

For messaging, there are other options:

- Azure Service Bus (queue / topics)
- Azure Event Hubs
- Azure Queue

and for those ones, you'll find comparisson about when to use each one of them.

Comment: Thank you, I will update my question but I'm looking for differences between Azure SignalR and Azure Service Bus

Comment: friend, they solve different problems. You're pretty much trying to find differences between a bird and a lion

Comment: based on what I know of both and what I've read they are both used to send messages between applications/components of an application

Comment: agreed, but if you need bi-directional messages near real time (signalr), with you just use to decouple services, use the others

Comment: I think @ThiagoCustodio is right, you cannot use a comparisson to pick one or another. You need SignalR or not, you need a Queue or not. You can need both, one or none. It is like questioning if you need a Hard Drive or Wifi instead

Comment: Given they are so different I think it would be easy to explain some of the differences rather than making metaphores about how obvious they might be. This is not answering the question.

Comment: there are no metaphores in my answer, just said they solve different problems.

Answer (score 4):

So, while doing some research I found a comparison between Azure Service Bus and Azure SignalR Service that tackles everything:

• Time to "hello world": In terms of signing up, both Azure Service Bus and Azure SignalR Service take about the same time to setup a new account and publish the first message.

• Realtime features: Pub/sub messaging is present in Azure service bus but it’s limited in Azure SignalR. However, you can make use of pub/sub in SignalR by using a combination of backplanes such as Redis or Event Grid which supports the pub/sub model.

• Pricing: Azure Service Bus doesn't offer any free package, but Azure SignalR offers a free Azure SignalR Service unit, which has a cap of 20.000 messages per day and can sustain 20 concurrent connections.

And more.

Hope this helps anyone looking to get more information on the comparisons between both services.

[Azure Service Bus vs Azure SignalR Service](https://www.ably.io/compare/azure-service-bus-vs-azure-signalr-service)

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Service Bus**  - is a queue system. You can send bunch of messages to it and connect receivers that will process your messages. The important part here is that the process of sending the message to the queue and dequeuing (receiving) has acknowledgment system in place. In an example. Imagine API endpoint that signs up a user. You call an endpoint, you save new user to database and you send a message to a queue  with all data necessary to send a welcome email and then you return a response to user. Your API doesn't need to wait for your email server and deal with all failure that could have happened. Now your queue has a message and in most cases in Azure can be processed by Azure Function that can send that message via your email server and deal with retries in case of connection problems. This way you also save some computing resources because you can set to process it one by one instead of sending multiple emails all at once. Also when sending the message Service Bus acknowledges the message which means it is guaranteed it went onto the queue. Your receiver can also acknowledge the message aka in our example the email server can fail sending because of malformed message and so the message can be moved from Active Queue to a secondary queue called Dead Letter Queue (DLQ). This is great because you can move on and keep processing the remaining messages and inspect the failed messaged in DLQ. All in all the data is never lost.

**Azure SignalR** - it's designed to provide real time communication. Usually it is used in web and mobile apps to push real time data. Again in an example you can have a dashboard with orders list. When you open that Dashboard your client code connects to SignalR (keeps an active connection) and listens to broadcasted messages. Now imagine in your API you have a request to create an order, you can save it to your database and broadcast a message to SignalR with new order details. Your client code will receive and update your dashboard accordingly. Here is the biggest difference to Azure Service Bus, messages sent to SignalR (broadcasted) are processed immediately independently from connected clients. So if 10 users have orders dashboard opened they will all get the message, if nobody is on the dashboard the message is gone. If one of the users had temporary disconnection and got reconnected and between that time message was broadcasted, the message won't be received by that user.

**In your particular case** it seems you need to print thing out in remote locations.
Why not use https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/universal-print

If this can't be done I would go with Azure Service Bus and use **Service Bus Processor** that can continuously listen to messages in your Windows Service and process them.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample04_Processor.md